# Regular Expression - Capturing all repeating groups

Tags: java, regex

I have strings like below:

```
@property.one@some text here@property.two@another optional text here etc
```

which contains `@.+?@` strings inside.

I'd like to capture all these "variables" into groups via one regexp matching but it seems like it's not possible as regexp returns only last captured group while repeating.

Comment: Be careful, you may want `@[^@]+@` instead of `@.+@`

Comment: I forgot to put correct version, it should be "@.+?@

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're right; most regex flavors, Java included, do not allow access to individual matches of a repeated capturing group. (Perl 6 and .NET do allow this, for the record, but that's not helping you).

What else can you do?

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("@[^@]+@");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
    // match start: regexMatcher.start()
    // match end: regexMatcher.end()
}
```

That will capture `@property.one@`, `@property.two@` etc. one by one.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the separator will be `@`, then why not just use the [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method  (`string.split('@')`)?

Comment: It's not a separator it's a start/end "tag" of the property/placeholder

Comment: Well, in that case, couldn't you do the `split` anyway, traverse the resulting array and capture the property names and optional text?

Comment: How can you know in below examples which one is the property and which one is a text: "@property@text" and "text@property". Split gives you ["property", "text"] or ["text", property"].