# Regex to parse strings that might or might not be delimited by ; into several groups

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-group

I have a case where I need to parse a string into several groups depending on a criteria

For example the below;

```
01%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00;WAP_GPRS
```

should be 2 groups

```
%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00
WAP_GPRS
```

Notice that I dont care about 01 at the beginning and there can be 0 or more substrings delimited by ; and I need them all in their own group.

Another one;

```
01%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00;KPN;A23B
```

should be 3 groups:

```
%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00
KPN
A23B
```

Basically, I dont need to care if alpha or numeric comes first. The issue is grouping expressions into their own which can be 0 or more times. Meaning the below

```
01%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00
```

should produce also one group of `%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you need a regexp analog of split.  That would require a repeated capturing group.

Bad news, some people have looked into a similar problem and haven't found the right answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6836024/1665128

Good news, if you can live with some reasonable limit on the number of groups and you can add some code to identify the empty trailing ones, this may help:

```
([^;]*);?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?;?([^;]*)?
```

Comment: I thought the same. Now I agree that not knowing the number of substrings after the first ; (if there is one) makes it impossible to solve. So I decided to allow only 1 or 0 amount of substrings like 01%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00;KPN which would produce %3A%35r%07%01P%88%00 and KPN.. or 01%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00 which would produce %3A%35r%07%01P%88%00 .. What would be the regexp for that?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `split` your string on `;`.

But before that you would need to remove that `01` before the first `%`, by using `String#substring`, as you are not showing in your `required` output: -

```
  String str = "01%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00;WAP_GPRS";

  // Remove `01` before first `%`
  str = str.replace(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("%")), "");  

  String[] groups = str.split(";");
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(groups));
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
[%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00, WAP_GPRS]
```

Comment: I have to do it by regexp because the code I have to modify uses it heavily and other situations are dependent on it. So Regexp is a must unfortunately.

Comment: @Graham. Then you need to be more specific about what you want. Because what you have in your question right now, doesn't really need a Regexp

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regexp:

```
String data = "01%3A%35r%07%01P%88%00;KPN;A23B"

String groups = s.split(";")

for (String s: groups ){
     System.out.println(s); // I'm printing each separate group
}
```

The deleting of the first two letters of the original string is another thing that has nothing to do with the group separation and you can do it with the substring method.

Comment: As I mentioned before, our parsing implementation is using regex which is read from a registry so it's regex that I must use. I dont have an option

Comment: @graham You tagged the question with the "java" tag, that's why I thought you were using Java.

Comment: Oh we're using java although I can not touch the regexp usage since lots of other classes use the same regexp.

Comment: @graham You mean you already have the regexp that solves the problem ?

Comment: Our previous regexp was 01(*.) but that was only suited to one substring. then it was decided to add further keywords delimited by ;. Seeing that we can not group every added keyword by regexp without knowing the number of keywords, I decided to limit it 1. So now 01([^;]*);?([^;]*)? makes the trick