# How to select words having 3 and more characters between 2 words

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Below text is filtered from a huge text using a regex where i have to find sentences having dog and cat without porc and pig.

```
What, a Dog, a Rat, a Mouse, a Cat to scratch a man to
Where Iuliet liues, and euery Cat and Dog,
Which first (perchance) shee'l proue on Cats and Dogs,
glass, and from setting up memorials of departed cats and dogs.
Thinking,' etc., 1873, p. 82.), "A dog frames a general concept of cats or
dog, who never passed a cat who lay sick in a basket, and was a great
```

To find what is above I used the regex:

```
^(?!.\*porc.\*)(?!.\*pig.\*)(?=.\*\bdog\b.\*)(?=.\*\bcat\b.\*).\*
```

Now, I have to find words between dog and cat which have 3 characters and more.

I tried :

```
^(?!.\*porc.\*)(?!.\*pig.\*)(?=.\*\bdog\b.\*)(?=.\*\bcat\b.\*)dog(?:\s?\w{3,})+cat
```

It doesn't work.

Anyone have an idea on how to solve it?

Comment: In the given sample text, what precisely do you want to retrieve? I’m not quite clear on that. If you could show some sample output...

Comment: From my experience I can tell that regexes is not a good tool when a complicated logic is involved (like  searching for words between other words). I'd suggest using different tools to extract needed substrings and then apply simple search regexes to each substring.

Comment: You could have used `indexOf` to check rather than look-around in regex. And what is your expected output if the string has more than one `dog` and `cat`?

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying that my familiarity with Java is not the best (I answered the question before any language affiliation was declared). Having said this, I think your problem will require two regular expressions because (to my knowledge) Java does not support the capturing of repeated groups. In order to illustrate what you need, consider the overall pattern you are looking for. I have included the matches from your first example ("What, a Dog, a Rat, a Mouse, a Cat to scratch a man to") in double asterisks:

```
(?P<animal>    // Names the following group "animal" for later reference
    \b(dog|cat)    // **Dog**
)    // Ends "animal" group
[s]?\b\W+    // **, **
(?!\bporc\b\W+|\bpig\b\W+|(?P=animal)\W+)    // Not followed by porc, pig, or characters that match group "animal" (either 'cat' or 'dog')
.*?    // Characters up to first word of three characters or more **a **
(
    (
        (
            (
                (\b\w{3,}\b)    // The (repeated) group you are after (**Rat** / **Mouse**)
            \W+)+    // (**, ** / **, **)
        )
            (?:\b\w{0,2}\b\W+)*    // A group that will not be available after the search (**a ** / **a **)
        )+
    )
(?!    // Not followed by 
    (?P=animal)    // the characters that matched group "animal" above (either dog or cat)
)\b
(cat|dog)[s]{0,1}\b    // Followed by dog or cat, whichever was not the "animal" group above **Cat**
```

Since Java will only capture the last of the repeated groups (unlike .NET and other languages that allow one to capture repeated groups), you will most likely need to do your query in two steps. First, you will need to find all strings between cat(s) or dog(s) and dog(s) or cat(s) (as long as group one is not like group two). You can find these strings with a regular expression like the following:

```
(?P<animal>\b(dog|cat))[s]{0,1}\b\W+(?!\bporc\b\W+|\bpig\b\W+|(?P=animal)\W+)(.*?)(?!(?P=animal))\b(cat|dog)[s]{0,1}\b
```

You would want to find group 3, which is (.*?).

After you identify group 3 in each relevant string/sentence, you would want to use something like the following (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835970/regular-expression-capturing-all-repeating-groups)):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\b\w{3,}\b");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
    // match start: regexMatcher.start()
    // match end: regexMatcher.end()
}
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use just one (reasonable) regular expression to capture all the words you need in Java, since you never know how many three letter words will occur between the words dog and cat. I hope this helps.

Comment: I just updated the answer. I hope it's more clear in light of the fact that you are using Java.