# Match regex groups to list in java (Hearst Pattern)

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to match Hearst-Patterns with Java regex this is my regex:

```
<np>(\w+)<\/np> such as (?:(?:, | or | and )?<np>(\w+)<\/np>)*
```

If I have a annotated sentence like:

```
I have a <np>car</np> such as <np>BMW</np>, <np>Audi</np> or <np>Mercedes</np> and this can drive fast.
```

I want to get the groups:

```
1. car
2. [BMW, Audi, Mercedes]
```

**UPDATE:** Here is my current java code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<np>(\\w+)<\\/np> such as (?:(?:, | or | and )?<np>(\\w+)<\\/np>)*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I have a <np>car</np> such as <np>BMW</np>, <np>Audi</np> or <np>Mercedes</np> and this can drive fast.");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

But the 2nd group element only contains `Mercedes`, how can I get all the matches for the 2nd group (maby as array)? Is this possible with java `Pattern` and `Matcher`? And if yes, what is my mistake?

Comment: You will have to [`Pattern#find()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6836024/995891) repeated matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure to have contiguous results, you can use the `\G` anchor that forces a match to be contiguous to a precedent match:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<np>(\\w+)</np> such as|\\G(?:,| or| and)? <np>(\\w+)</np>");
```

note: the `\G` anchor means the end of a precedent match or the start of the string. To avoid to match the start of the string, you can add the lookbehind `(?<!^)` after the `\G`