# Regex. How to find similar parts after some text

Tags: java, regex

I have string `p[name]=[1111];[2222]` and i need to take from it 3 parts **`p[name]=`**, **`[1111]`** and **`[2222]`**. String can be different like `p[name]=[1111]` or `p[name]=[1111];[2222,[1,2,3],1];[3333]`
I'm trying to use regex for it, but can't find working solution.
My regex is

```
(p\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\]=)(?:(\\[.[^;]+\\]);?)+
```

When i run this code i have only two groups

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(p\\[[a-zA-Z0-9^=]+\\]=)(?:;*(\\[.[^;]+\\]))+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("p[name]=[1111];[2222]");
if (m.find()) {
    for(int i = 1, l = m.groupCount(); i <= l; ++i) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }   
}
```

Result is

```
p[name]=  
[2222]
```

Comment: first problem is with "repeating" group... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835970/regular-expression-capturing-all-repeating-groups  and for nested.... you can't do this with regexp (you need at least context free grammars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply do this?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("p\\[[a-z0-9]+]=|\\[[0-9]+]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("p[name]=[1111];[2222]");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

However, if you want to check the string structure at the same time, you can use this kind of pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(p\\[[a-z0-9]+]=)|\\G(?<!^)(\\[[0-9]+])(?:;|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("p[name]=[1111];[2222]");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println((m.group(1))? m.group(1) : m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what this part of regex doing `\\G(?<!^)` ?

Comment: @cooperok: `\G` is an anchor and means "contiguous to a precedent match or to the start of the string". To forbid the subpattern to match at the start of the string, I added a negative lookbehind `(?<!^)` ("not preceded by the start of the string")

Answer (score 0):

I can give you this regex. That should also work with this: p[name]=[1111];[2222,[1,2,3],1]

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([p]+)|\[[a-z0-9\,\[\]]+\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("p[name]=[1111];[2222]");
if (m.find()) {
    for(int i = 1, l = m.groupCount(); i <= l; ++i) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }   
}
```