# Java split on space using regexp?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match and capture the command and parameters from the following input:

```
!command param1 param2
```

I am using Java's classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`:

```
private Pattern regExp = Pattern.compile(
        "^!(?<command>[^\\s]*)((?:\\s+)(?<param>[^\\s]*))*$");

public String command() {
    m = regExp.matcher(getMsg());
    return m.matches() ? m.group("command") : "";
}

public String param(int index) {
    return m.group(index);
}
```

also using this (http://fiddle.re/yanta6) to experiment ....

some pointer and help appreciated!

Comment: So what's your question? Your pattern looks ok.

Comment: Your title says "split on space". Did you try splitting on spaces? As for your question, you can only capture the last `<param>`. This question is probably a duplicate: [Regular Expression - Capturing all repeating groups](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6835970/7586)

Comment: Note that you can't have a variable number of capture groups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups  You would have to match the entire params substring, and then split that match on space or whatever.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nQ9gW0/1

Comment: @karl What's your expected output? You could do this through only regex...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't use a regex for this.  If your input is

```
!command param1 param2 paramX
```

Then normal string manipulation would do the job nicely.  Just discard the opening ! and then use a split on " "

Comment: Fair enough, that would ofc work but even if I didn't mention it I will need to make this somewhat configurabel, preferable by someone that is better at regexp than me :)

Comment: params.addAll(Arrays.asList(getMsg().split("\\s+")));

Answer (score 2):

You could do this through regex..

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:^!(?<Command>\\S+)|)\\s+(?<params>\\S+)");
String input = "!command param1 param2 param3 paramn param3 param4";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while(matcher.find())
{
    if(matcher.group("Command") != null)
    {
    System.out.println(matcher.group("Command"));
    }
    if(matcher.group("params") != null)

    System.out.println(matcher.group("params"));
}
```

Output:

```
command
param1
param2
param3
paramn
param3
param4
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nQ9gW0/3)