# Regex capture group within repetition

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract every integer value from a string.  The string has sections that repeat, from 1 to 7 times.  Each section has 4 integer values.

```
kjlfdiuadfj FOO1:   176 3171    441 FOO2:   164 4499    340 FOO3:   1812    7244    1255    FOO4:   288 5290    771 jkajkdfldj
```

I am trying to build a regex to uniquely identify each integer in each repeating section.

```
(FOO(\d):\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+){1,7}
```

When I run this pattern, the regex group matches are as follows:

```
1: <The entire original string>
2: 4
3: 288
4: 5290
5: 771
```

Notice groups 2-5 match only the last (4th) repetition.  Why aren't the first 3 repetitions matched?  How can I extract all 4 integers from each repetition?

Comment: It's because you're repeating a capturing group, which will only capture the last match. Searching for that, you can find Java examples on how to handle capturing repetitions, for example, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835970/regular-expression-capturing-all-repeating-groups) could be adapted for your use case. It boils down to eliminating the outer capturing group altogether, using `find()` to find occurrences of a match, and then pulling the data from the individual groups in a loop.

Comment: @nickb Ok, I see what you are getting at.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Just use [`\bFOO(\d):\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/nG4bA3/1) and grab each captured group using `while (matcher.find())` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice groups 2-5 match only the last (4th) repetition. Why aren't the first 3 repetitions matched? How can I extract all 4 integers from each repetition?

I am confident that you will find that group 1 also matches only the fourth repetition.  Group 0, on the other hand, will always correspond to the entire match -- I suspect that's what you saw.

This behavior is documented in [the API docs for java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> Capturing groups are numbered by counting their opening parentheses from left to right.

[...]

> Group zero always stands for the entire expression.

[...]

> The captured input associated with a group is always the subsequence that the group most recently matched.

That's all quite standard across different regex implementations.

Instead of capturing it all at once, you could process the String one piece at a time by means of `Matcher.find()` and / or `Matcher.lookingAt()`, using a pattern that corresponds to exactly one of the repeat units.  After each successful match, extract and store the captured groups for that match.

Comment: Yes, sorry, group 0 is correct.  It does appear I must utilize some sort of loop.  Thanks.