# java regex - capture repeated groups

Tags: java, regex, capture-group

I'm using Java's regex library. I want to validate a string against the following format:

```
31,5,46,7,86(...)
```

The amount of numbers is not known. I want to make sure there is at least one number in that string, and that every two numbers are separated by a comma. I also want to get the numbers from the string.

(**Note:** this is just a simplified example, string.split will not solve my actual problem)

I wrote the following regex:

```
({[0-9]++)((?:,[0-9]++)*+)
```

The validation part works. However, when I try to extract the numbers, I get 2 groups:

```
Group1: 31
Group2: ,5,46,7,86
```

regex101 version: https://regex101.com/r/xJ5oQ6/3

Is there a way I can get each number separately? i.e. to end up with the collection:

```
[31, 5, 46, 7, 86]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you get it recursively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java does not allow you to access the individual matches of a repeated capturing group. For more information look at this question: [Regular Expression - Capturing all repeating groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835970/regular-expression-capturing-all-repeating-groups)

The code provided by Tim Pietzcker can help you as well. If you rework it a bit and add a special case for the first number you can use something like this:

```
String target = "31,5,46,7,86";

Pattern compileFirst = Pattern.compile("(?<number>[0-9]+)(,([0-9])+)*");
Pattern compileFollowing = Pattern.compile(",(?<number>[0-9]+)");

Matcher matcherFirst = compileFirst.matcher(target);
Matcher matcherFollowing = compileFollowing.matcher(target);

System.out.println("matches: " + matcherFirst.matches());
System.out.println("first: " + matcherFirst.group("number"));

int start = 0;
while (matcherFollowing.find(start)) {
    String group = matcherFollowing.group("number");

    System.out.println("following: " + start + " - " + group);
    start = matcherFollowing.end();
}
```

This outputs:

```
matches: true
first: 31
following: 0 - 5
following: 4 - 46
following: 7 - 7
following: 9 - 86
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
/(?=[0-9,]+$)((?<=,|^)[0-9]{1,2})(?=,|$)/g
```

The above captures one or two digits followed by `,` or end of input.

Note that I used the `g`lobal modifier.

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/xJ5oQ6/6)

Comment: Now the captures are working, but the validation isn't: I tried to add a letter in the middle and instead of 'no match' [i got this](https://regex101.com/r/xJ5oQ6/5).
Your suggestion is the closest I've got to what I wanted though, any ideas how to tweak it?

Comment: @RoyMillo I updated the regex, but what you want is not possible to put in one PCRE regex, since dynamic length lookbehinds are not supported. I don't know what regex flavor Java is using.

Comment: Your validation regex could however look something like this: `/^[0-9,]+$/`